# Wait for the format change of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, face-detection, cropperjs

during a project I need to set up a cropper associated with a face detection. The face detection works well but the cropper modifies the format of the image with its object, the coordinates returned by the facedetector are false. Do you know how to apply the facedetector once the image has been modified with the cropper interface ?

```
  var image = document.getElementById('img');
  var cropper = new Cropper(image, {
    /*      aspectRatio: 9 / 16,*/
    // autoCrop: true,
    scalable: false,
    cropBoxResizable: false,
    guides: true,
    dragMode: 'none',
    preview: '.preview',
    data:{
      width: 250,
      height:  325,
    },
    crop: function(e) {
      $('#x').val(e.detail.x);
      $('#y').val(e.detail.y);
      $('#w').val(e.detail.width);
      $('#h').val(e.detail.height);
    },
  });
  $('#img').faceDetection({
    complete: function (faces) {
      console.log(faces)
      initx = faces[0].x;
      inity = faces[0].y;
      cropper.data({x:120,y:init});
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to first, get the coords, then initiate `Cropper` with those coordinates, like this:

```js
const img = $('img');
img.faceDetection({
  complete: function (faces) {
    initCropper(faces[0]);
  }
});

function initCropper(data) {
  cropper = new Cropper(img[0], {
    data
  });
}
```

https://jsbin.com/keruzal/edit?js,output

Comment: thanks for your reponse but your solution return me error : `Uncaught DOMException: Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount` do you have an idea how to solve this problem ?

Comment: Are you sure it finds faces? Can you reproduce the issue in jsbin or something so I could try to debug it?